# Is there a way to see the property artifacts for a particular profile?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to see the final property artifacts without launching spring boot app?

For example, suppose the following application.yml exists:

```
hoge: hoge-value

---

spring.config.activate.on-profile: local

bar: bar-local-value

---

spring.config.activate.on-profile: production

hoge: hoge-production-value
bar: bar-production-value
```

When using local/production profile, the following property artifacts can be created.

```
# local:
hoge: hoge-value
bar: var-local-value

# production
hoge: hoge-production-value
bar: var-production-value
```

I know that I can check it by launching the spring boot app in each profile and calling `/actuator/env` endpoint.

But I don't want to launch spring boot App with production profile on local PC.
(To be exact, the spring boot app cannot be started because the bean initialization fails due to Network ACL etc.)

I'd like to make sure that each profile is correct when I make major changes to application.yml. Is there a good way?